# Reload the xml camel context into same camel context that is already reg

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, apache-camel-3

Requirement is to load the spring xml camel context that is available in table into application (Single XML has both context and routes in it). When application starts, need to read this xml from table load into application.

for ex, assume the below xml is available in a table and need to read this from table and load into application when sprint boot application starts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                                http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">                  
    <camelContext id="myContext">       
        <route id="FileReadRoute">
            <from uri="file:///Users/Data?noop=false&amp;idempotent=false&amp;delay=30s" />
            <split streaming="true">
                <tokenize token="\n"/>
                <log message="print the body message: ${body}" />
            </split>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I am able to read the xml from table and load into application using the below piece of code and its loaded the context with the name of "myContext" because that's the name I am passing from xml.

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext  newContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(resource.getBytes()); //resource holds the XML context information from table.
newContext.load(resource);
newContext.refresh();
```

now the second requirement is, during runtime without bring down the application, I want to refresh the camel context. for example, if I make some changes on the XML context in table and if I execute a api (called refresh api), then existing camel context to be shutdown and reload the new data with the same context name.

Example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                                    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">                  
        <camelContext id="myContext">       
            <route id="FileReadRoute">
                <from uri="file:///Users/Data?noop=false&amp;idempotent=false&amp;delay=30s" />
                <split streaming="true">
                    <tokenize token="\n"/>
                    <log message="print the body message: ${body}" />
                    <log message="newly updated log message, print the body message: ${body}" />
                </split>
            </route>
        </camelContext>
    </beans>
```

I have added the one additional line in the xml. now if I execute refresh api, it should refresh the existing context and load the updated one. but what's happening here is, its not unregister the existing context "myContex" in camel context, instead it creates new context with the name of "myContext-1". I understand that its a pattern by default camel uses to register the context in Mbean if one already registered. but I am looking for an option to not to register with new name. I want the same name to be used by either unregister the existing one and re-register again. I am not sure how can we unregister it.

```
<log message="newly updated log message, print the body message: ${body}" />
```

I am actually using the below piece of code to refresh it.

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext  newRefereshContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
            newRefereshContext.setParent(applicationContext);
            newRefereshContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(true);
            newRefereshContext.load(resource);
            newRefereshContext.refresh();
            newRefereshContext.start();
```

The reason why I create new instance of GenericXmlApplicationContext() is, I am unable to use refresh() method more than once as I get error throwing the error message that "context can't refreshed more than once".

Other alternative I tried was, remove the "myContext" bean definition from the GenericXmlApplicationContext() instance. yes, it was working for first time but when I try the same technique for next time to refresh, "myContext" is not in GenericXmlApplicationContext instance. I think the problem is, when I create new GenericXmlApplicationContext() instance, not sure whether it is registered in the application. how do I get all instance of GenericXmlApplicationContext() and remove the bean of "myContext" in it and the recreate the bean with the same name.

The below is what I tried earlier:

```
    @Autowired
    GenericXmlApplicationContext springContext;

CamelContext existingCamelContext = (CamelContext) springContext.getBean("myContext");
existingCamelContext.stop();
springContext.removeBeanDefinition("myContext");

    GenericXmlApplicationContext  newContext = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(resource.getBytes()); //resource holds the XML context information from table.
    newContext.load(resource);
    newContext.refresh();
```

Thanks in advance.. Appriciate if someone can provide some information regarding this..

Comment: HI @James Mark ,
Did you got any solution. I am currently having the same scenario in my application.